# Applescript changing variable names between computers

Tags: variables, numbers, applescript

I'm having a very strange problem that may be the result of my ignorance of how Applescript handles variable names. I've written a script that works fine on my computer.  It references variables from the dictionaries of a couple of programs, I'll use an example from Numbers here since it's better known.  On my computer, the following works fine:

```
tell application "Numbers"
activate
tell document 1
tell sheet 1
delete table 1
```

When the same script is loaded into another computer it looks like this:

```
tell application "Numbers"
activate
tell document 1
tell <<class NmSh>> 1
delete <<class NmTb>> 1
```

And, of course, it can't find `<<class NmSh>>`.

Any suggestions? Numbers automatically comes up with document 1 and sheet 1, and using those variable names works correctly on my computer.

Comment: Does the other computer have the Numbers application installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the names of classes, not variables. When AppleScript cannot load the scripting terminology for an application, it displays the codes it uses internally, as you have seen.
Your problem is that AppleScript cannot find the Numbers application on the second computer.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, I'm 99% sure the other computer has Numbers, and 100% sure it has the other application involved which is throwing the same kind of error. Is there something that could cause Applescript not to see the application?

Comment: They could be different versions of Numbers. Applescript implementations can, and will, change from version to version.

Comment: In AppleScript Editor on the second computer, try using "File > Open Dictionary..." and opening Numbers.